# creating a barplot showing frequency of samples using carcinoma dataset

Tags: r, statistics

I was working on an assignment and I came across a problem that I am confused on. I am a beginner level R studio user and am unsure how to do this problem. I know how to make general barplots, but I am thrown off by how to make this specific barplot, especially subtracting 1. This is working with the carcinoma dataset.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The carcinoma data comes from the **poLCA** package.

```
library(poLCA)
data(caricoma)
?carcinoma
```

According to the help page, the data represent dichotomous ratings by seven pathologists. 1="no" and 2="yes". So subtracting 1 and taking the column sums should give you the frequencies for each pathologist.

```
colSums(carcinoma-1)
# A  B  C  D  E  F  G 
#66 79 45 32 71 25 66
```

Graphing is facilitated by reshaping into long form so we get only two columns.

```
library(tidyverse)

carcinoma %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  mutate(value=value-1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=name, y=value)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! This helped a lot.